# What is the best way to solve CORS issue - in Frontend with Angular proxy or in Backend with @CrossOrigin in Spring Boot?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I work for a company let's say CompanyA has an API/SaaS. CompanyA has hundreds of partners, each of whom have their own website. The partners would like to incorporate CompanyA's API into a section of their website using `iframe`. It's something like a contact form for something very specific.

My backend is Spring Boot, my frontend is Angular using NX monorepo.
While testing a webapp incorporated into another webapp using iframe, it seems that I get the CORS issue. I can solve that and it seems I only need to allow access to our own app which will be incorporated into the partners' websites.

Questions:

1. is it better to configure the CORS issue in the backend or in the frontend using proxy config?
2. are there any performance differences?
3. is there any security feature that should be added in something like this? It's a contact form with contact information (so I guess GDPR).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring security you have to create proper config there. CrossOrigin annotation should be enough in your controller classes. For example you may have problems in WebsecurityConfig in "requestMatcher" but on the website it displays "CrossOrigin problem".